# What's the difference between escaping, filtering, validating and sanitizing?

Tags: terminology, validation

An application needs to handle input and output of untrusted data carefully. As the case may be, values have to be **escaped**, **filtered**, **validated** or **sanitized**. There often seems to be a sloppy and interchangeable use of these terms although they are obviously not all equivalent.

I'm looking for a clarifying overview about the differences and the correct usage in a security context.

Comment: Escaping, filtering, sanitizing = same thing depending on context. Validating = ensuring that input conforms to specific restrictions (length, format, etc).

Comment: @MarkBuffalo Apparently others see more differences, though: https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Answer (score 24):

**Escaping**.  Converting a control character to its escape sequence.  For example, a `<` symbol may be converted to `&lt;` so that the characters following the `<` are not interpreted as an XML tag instead of XML content.

**Filtering**.  Like escaping, but instead of replacing the control character, it is simply removed.

**Validated.**  Comparison of an input against a white list or regular expression to detect control characters or other character sequences that would trigger an unauthorized behavior.  For example, an account number entered by a user might be validated against a list of account numbers known to be tied to the user.

**Sanitized.**  A combination of escaping, filtering, and validation that ensures that an input to a system function does not trigger an unexpected and unauthorized behavior.

Comment: This matches the general usage I've seen.

Comment: What about "input validation"?  Are these all forms of that?